# Access TabHost from another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I need to make a TabHost changeable from all Activitys. I have done some reasearch, but I have not found anything compatible with TabHost.

I want to be able to hide the TabHost from another Activity.(If I manage to access it, hiding it will not be a problem for me)

I have earlier worked with some public statics but not been able to make it work with a TabHost. The reason I need it to be changeable from all Activitys, is that the TabHost should only disapear on a result from a spesific Activity.

The TabHost is stock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get `tabhost` in child activity as

```
yourTabActivity activity = (yourTabActivity) this.getParent();
TabHost host = activity.getTabHost();
```

Comment: Thank you, it has helped me.